# change 2D array to 2D vector in c++

Tags: c++

I wanna change this array to vector

```
  len = numberOfPlayer();
  float cost[len][len];
```

I change this code to the code below but it doesn't work

```
  vector<vector<float> > cost(len) ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to just default initialize a `len` by `len` matrix you can do this:

```
vector<vector<float>> cost(len, vector<float>(len));
```

This uses the [fill constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) to create `len` `vector<float>`s, with each of those `vector<float>`s being of size `len` with defaulted values (`float()`).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This answers the original question posted.

Assuming C++11 support, it should be

```
vector<vector<float> > cost = {
    { 1.000000000, 2.000000000, 3.000000000 },
    { 1.000000000, 1.414213562, 2.236067977 },
    { 1.414213562, 1.000000000, 1.414213562 }
};
```

Comment: What about the size of interior vector ?   in this exampel i have 3 row what about when it's more or less?

Comment: cost.size() == 3; cost[0].size() == 3; What about them? You have a vector of vectors of floats. Each internal vector represents a row (or column) of floats and can have arbitrary size.

Comment: @MohammadrezaHasanzadeh That's a slightly different question. Your question involves a 2d array of identical dimensions.

Comment: sorry yes. but that was just an example i have a function for push value in my vector.

Comment: @NeilKirk yes thanks. Sorry my mistake. I'm toddler